# How do I remove duplicate SQL results?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-order-by, inner-join, duplicates

I am pulling access, guildid, name from a table called **guildmembers**

[image]
.

...and id, level, playerclass from another table called **players**

[image]

Here's my SQL statement:

```
SELECT guildmembers.access, guildmembers.guildid, guildmembers.name, players.id, players.level, players.playerclass
FROM guildmembers, players
ORDER BY guildmembers.name, players.playerclass
```

Here's what returns.

[image]

Here's what I need.

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need to do is a join statement. currently you are telling sql to just show you all resutls from both tables. you want to show the results only where they match and for this you use a join statement.

```
SELECT guildmembers.access, guildmembers.guildid, guildmembers.name, players.id, players.level, players.playerclass
FROM guildmembers join players on guildmembers.pid=players.id
ORDER BY guildmembers.name, players.playerclass
```

`guildmembers.pid` and `players.id` are the common field in both tables so you join the tables on these.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

to make this easier to follow and understand have a common field name in both tables. you can then use this to join and it makes more sense.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I can't believe I forgot about joins. It's been a long long day. Thanks Smudger! :) Common field names is on my list of stuff to improve. (e.g. from my TODO.txt file: "Change gid in guilds table to guildid for consistancy.")

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Statement is not correct, please try

```
SELECT guildmembers.access, guildmembers.guildid, guildmembers.name, players.id, 
players.level, players.playerclass from guildmembers left join players on guildmembers.pid = players.id order by guildmembers.name, players.playerclass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT gm.access as access, gm.guildid as guildid, gm.name as name, 
p.id as id, p.level as level, p.playerclass as playerclass
FROM guildmembers gm LEFT JOIN players p on gm.pid=p.id
ORDER BY gm.name, p.playerclass
```